# How do you create an animated LineChart in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, charts, scenebuilder

I have created a LineChart in SceneBuilder and am trying to workout how to data to it, so that it will be drawn live. 
In my `Controller` class, I have:

```
    public class Controller {    
        ...    
        @FXML private LineChart<Number, Number> chart;
        @FXML private NumberAxis xAxis, yAxis;
        private XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series;
        private boolean run = true;
        ...

        public init() {
            xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
            xAxis.setTickLabelsVisible(false);
            xAxis.setTickMarkVisible(false);
            xAxis.setMinorTickVisible(false);

            series = new XYChart.Series<Number, Number>();
            series.setName("Data plot"); 

            chart.setAnimated(false);
            chart.getData().addAll(series);           
        }  

        ...
        //When a button is clicked, a signal is sent to my server that starts a 
        //tracking application. Then it enters the while loop. This code
        //then makes requests to the server for data (getData()).
        //This is the data that I would like to display.
        @FXML
        private track() {
            connection.startTracking();

            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                while(run) {
                    int[] data = connection.getData() //from somewhere else
                    dataManager.dataToSeries(data, series);

                    if(!series.getData.isEmpty()) {
                        chart.getData().retainAll();
                        chart.getData.addAll(series);
                    }
                }
            }
       }
  }
```

And here is the `dataToSeries()` method from `dataController`

```
...
private void dataToSeries(int[] data, XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series) {
    int yValue = 0;
    int len = data.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(data[i], yValue);  
        yValue++;
    }
 }
```

If I print out the series in `Controller`, I get the data that i expect, however it is in the form:

`Series: [Data[11,1,null], Data[16,2,null], Data[21,3,null]`

Can anyone explain why this data isn't being displayed on my `LineChart`?

Comment: IDK how `addToChart` is called, but since it contains a infinite loop, this could easily block the UI thread preventing any updates of the user interface. On the other hand if it's run on a different thread, you're updating the UI from a non-application thread, which is also bad...

Comment: Sorry, I'll update my code to try and make it clearer. I tried to leave out code that wasn't relevant

Comment: I've included a description of the `addToChart()` method, which I have now changed to be called `track()` (which is it's actual name in my program)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're blocking the UI thread with the `Runnable` you post on the application thread using `Platform.runLater`.

Since the `track()` method is annotated with `@FXML` I suspect this is used as a `EventHandler` in the fxml file and therefore runs on the application thread anyways which removes the necessity of using `Platform.runLater` to run the code on the application thread.

To not block the UI thread the loop should run on a non-application thread and only the UI updates should be done on the application thread. Furthermore a break small break between updates may not be wrong. In this case a `ScheduledExecutorService` could provide suitable scheduling:

Example `Application` code:

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
private ScheduledFuture future;

private Random random = new Random();

private int[] getData() {
    int[] result = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        result[i] = random.nextInt(10);
    }
    return result;
}

private static void dataToSeries(int[] data, XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series) {
    int len = data.length;

    int size = series.getData().size();
    if (size > len) {
        series.getData().subList(len, series.getData().size()).clear();
    } else if (size < len) {
        for (; size < len; size++) {
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(0, size));
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        series.getData().get(i).setXValue(data[i]);
    }
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ToggleButton btn = new ToggleButton("updating");
    btn.setSelected(false);

    XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();

    LineChart<Number, Number> chart = new LineChart<>(new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis(), FXCollections.observableArrayList(series));
    chart.setAnimated(false);

    Runnable dataGetter = () -> {
        try {
            // simulate some delay caused by the io operation
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
        int[] data = getData();
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            // update ui
            dataToSeries(data, series);
        });
    };

    btn.selectedProperty().addListener((a, b, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue) {
            // update every second
            future = service.scheduleWithFixedDelay(dataGetter, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } else {
            // stop updates
            future.cancel(true);
            future = null;
        }
    });

    VBox root = new VBox(10, chart, btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

@Override
public void stop() throws Exception {
    service.shutdownNow();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I see what you mean. I will try to integrate your suggestions into my code

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be working. I didn't realise that I was blocking any threads

Answer (score 0):

Based [Java SE Development Demos and Samples Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) in `rootFoder -> jdk.x.x.x -> demo -> javafx_samples` execute Ensemble8.jar.

Within the application go to the section `charts` and search for `LineChart`

You should see something like that
[Image from Ensembre Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzRb6.png)

Then click in **View Source**

Here is an example of an implementation.

```
@FXML
private LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart;

@FXML
private NumberAxis xAxis;

@FXML
private NumberAxis yAxis;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    lineChart.setTitle("Stock Monitoring, 2010");
    ObservableList<XYChart.Series<Number,Number>> dataChart =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new LineChart.Series("Serie 1",FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                            new XYChart.Data<>(1,2),
                            new XYChart.Data<>(5,3),
                            new XYChart.Data<>(9,3),
                            new XYChart.Data<>(2,7),
                            new XYChart.Data<>(6,9),
                            new XYChart.Data<>(1,2)
                    )),
                    new LineChart.Series<>("Series 2",FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                            new XYChart.Data<>(5,7),
                            new XYChart.Data<>(3,4),
                            new XYChart.Data<>(8,2),
                            new XYChart.Data<>(6,9),
                            new XYChart.Data<>(1,3),
                            new XYChart.Data<>(9,7)
                    )));

    lineChart.setData(dataChart);
```

For example to change `the "y" axis` of the second point of the first list `Serie 1`whose current value is (x: 5, y: 3)  would look something like this

```
dataChart.get(0).getData().get(1).setYValue(9);
```